# MS Access 365, Chart, Scatter Plot

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, graph, scatter-plot

I would like to create a scatter plot in an Access form. The data will be illustrated from selected probands in the frontend MS Access application.

I am working with Microsft 365. I thought I could copy an Excel Graph (scatter plot) into an Access form and then I would modify the data using VBA.

How could I modify the data for the Excel chart in Access?

In the past, I had used MS Graph Chart object. However, in Microsft 365 the old MSGraph.Chart.8 version does not works very well. Also, I could not update the MSGraph Chart.

In MS Access 2003 and MSGraph.Chart.8 it worked with
`select GAdecimal,weight,P3,P10,P25,P50,P75,P90,P97 from q1_wt_chart`

Could someone please help me how to modify the plot data in a way that it updates for selected probands.

Thanks

Niels

Comment: What's wrong with the query you show? What do you mean by 'updates for selected' - update when and selected how?

Comment: Hello,the query is fine. This issue arises that I cannot show the data. The MSGraph.Chart.8 object is not working well with Access 365. I tried to copy a power point chart into Access and than

Comment: Then what is the issue? Provide sample data, attempted code, error messages. I have used VBA to modify MSGraph chart objects. Sorry, can't help with Access365 issues. I use Access 2010. Could try viewing Excel or PowerPoint through a WebBrowser control but that likely will not be useful for report output. If you want to make a jpg from Excel or PowerPoint and then load jpg onto report, then specify that in your question.

Comment: Hello,the query is fine. This issue arises that I cannot show the data. The MSGraph.Chart.8 object is not working well with Access 365. I tried to copy a power point chart into Access. Unfortunately, Access show an error. The OLE-server had an error. Further the new diagram element does not support scatter plots.