# Scatter plot with Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

Is there a possibility to create a scatter plot using Microsoft Access 365?
The Modern Chart option does not allow scatter plots.

Thank you
Niels

Comment: Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931741/ms-access-365-chart-scatter-plot and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/how-to-create-a-x-y-scatter-plot-in-access-2016/eaf3e529-7f9b-4a3a-b1c0-61b8b98c86ae

Comment: If you want more attention on an old question, try a bounty, don't re-ask